# Can't get Firestore rules to let me read my own documents

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `books` collection in Firestore. Every book has `authorUid` property on it.
And I am getting Insufficient permissions error when I try to read collection of my books while being logged in.

These are my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    function isAuth(){
    return request.auth != null;
  }
  
  function isOwner(book){
      return request.auth.uid == book.authorUid;
  }
  
  function isValidBook(book){
    return (
      book.title is string &&
      book.title != '' &&
      
      book.description is string
    )
  }
  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if isAuth();
    }
    
    match /books/{book}{
      allow read: if isAuth() && isOwner(request.resource.data);
      
      allow create: if isAuth() &&
        isOwner(request.resource.data) &&
        isValidBook(request.resource.data);
        
      allow update: if isAuth() &&
        isOwner(request.resource.data) &&
        isOwner(resource.data) &&
        isValidBook(request.resource.data);
        
      allow delete: if isAuth() &&
        isOwner(resource.data);
    }
  }
}
```

In vue/vuex I am using this code to perform CRUD operations (snippets):

```
const getBooks = () => db.collection('books');
const getOwnBooks = (uid: string) => getBooks().where('authorUid', '==', uid);

export const actions: ActionTree<BookState, RootState> & Actions = {
    [ActionTypes.Listen]({ commit, rootGetters }) {
        const user = rootGetters[USER_GETTER];
        unsubscribe = getOwnBooks(user.uid).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            // ...
        });
    },

    [ActionTypes.Unlisten]() {
        unsubscribe();
    },

    async [ActionTypes.CreateBook]({ rootGetters }, payload) {
        const user = rootGetters[USER_GETTER];
        await getBooks().doc().set({ ...payload, authorUid: user.uid });
    },

    async [ActionTypes.DeleteBook](_, { bookId }) {
        await getBooks().doc(bookId).delete();
    },

    async [ActionTypes.UpdateBook](_, { bookId, update }) {
        await getBooks().doc(bookId).set(update, { merge: true });
    },
}
```

Comment: Seems like `isOwner(request.resource.data)` on `read` is not necessary. But I am too fresh into Firebase to tell if removing this part makes the query unsafe...